# Angular "APP_INITIALIZER" to have service without promise in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular5

I have an app which is present in an iframe of parent application.

When my app which is within iFrame loads, in my applications AppModule, i have an APP_INITIALIZER called tokenService. This service sends a window.sendMessage to parent application to get token. So there is a "message" event handler in the token service.

Below is the code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigurationService } from './configService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class tokenService {

  private _configs;
  private msgId = this.newId();
  private messageToGetToken = {
    'id': this.msgId,
    'type': 'test/V/GetToken',
    'data': null
  };

  constructor(private configService: ConfigurationService) {
    this._configs = configService.getConfigurationData();
  }

  getToken() {
    if (this._configs.loginRequired == true) {
      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('message', this.processMessage, false);
      }
      else {
        (<any>window).attachEvent("onmessage", this.processMessage);
      }

      parent.window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(this.messageToGetToken), '*');

      return Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message')
        .subscribe((messageEvent: MessageEvent) => { this.processMessage(messageEvent); });
    }
  }

  private processMessage(evt) {
    var result = JSON.parse(evt);
    if (result && result.responseFor && result.responseFor === this.msgId) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', result.data ? result.data[0] : null);
      console.log(result.data);
    }
    console.log(evt);
  }

  private newId() {
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  };
}
```

The method "processMessage" gets called when the result comes back.

The "tokenService" has been set as an "APP_INITIALIZER". Below is the code:

```
{
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': loadService,
      'deps': [ConfigurationService, tokenService],
      'multi': true,
    },
```

---

The configService is initialized too:

```
export function loadConfig(config: ConfigurationService): Function {
  return () => config.configuration$;
}
{
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': loadConfig,
      'deps': [ConfigurationService],
      'multi': true,
}
```

---

In app.module.ts file, there is method:

```
export function loadService(tService: tokenService): Function {
  return () => tService.getToken();
}
```

I am not sure how to make this event handler: "processMessage" as promise method. Can anyone help me with that? 
Because i get an error when i try to run the application. The error is:

```
ERROR TypeError: tService.getToken is not a function
    at Array.eval (app.module.ts:44)
    at ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers (core.js:3569)
```

Also, i want to make this tokenService complete its execution, before other components in my application get initialized. How to make sure that tokenService has completed execution and the event handler for sendMessage is called, before the app continues to load other components?

The code for configuration service is below:

```
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
  private configuration;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getConfiguration(): Promise<any> {
      let ret = this.http.get('appConfig.json').map(
        res => this.configuration = res.json())
        .toPromise()
        .then((data: any) => {
          this.configuration = data;
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log("error while reading app config!");
        });

      return ret.then((x) => {
      });
    }

    getConfigurationData(): any {
      return this.configuration;
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the question have `angular5` tag if you're using Angular 4? Any way, `angular` tag should be used, unless you're sure that the problem is version-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tService.getToken` is undefined because DI went wrong, and `tService` is actually `ConfigurationService`. `[ConfigurationService, tokenService]` annotation means that 2 dependencies will be injected, while factory function has only 1 parameter.

If it doesn't use `ConfigurationService`, it doesn't have to be injected.

`getToken` already returns an observable. `APP_INITIALIZER` expects a promise for asynchronous initializations, so an observable should be converted to a promise:

```
'deps': [tokenService],
  'multi': true,
},
```

and

```
export function loadService(tService: tokenService): Function {
  return () => tService.getToken().toPromise();
}
```

The problem with `ConfigurationService` is that it is asynchronous yet it exposes only the result of that promise that will be available with `getConfigurationData` at some point. While calling `getConfiguration` multiple times will result in recurring requests. It should expose a promise or an observable that can be easily chained:

```
export class ConfigurationService {
  public configurationPromise = this.getConfiguration().toPromise();
  public configuration;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.configurationPromise.then(configuration => {
      this.configuration = configuration;
    });
  }

  private getConfiguration(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('appConfig.json').map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

Then `configurationPromise` can be chained anywhere and it's not limited to promise control flow:

```
export class tokenService {
  ...
  constructor(private configService: ConfigurationService) {}

  getToken(): Observable<any> {
    ...
    return Observable.fromPromise(configService.configurationPromise)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message'))
    .map((messageEvent: MessageEvent) => this.processMessage(messageEvent))
    .take(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! how do i make the configurationService execute first and then the token service?

Comment: Is there a way to make configService execute a function before tService.getToken() is called?

Comment: What's configService? Your code doesn't contain configurationService, while it's relevant here.

Comment: ConfigurationService basically reads configuration from app.config file. So i want that service to executed first. How can i do that? I will add the config section above in the question.

Comment: What is getConfigurationData? What does it return? Is it async? This is the thing that matters.

Comment: How can i initialize configService first and then tokenService? Is it possible to set a dependency while loading?

Comment: ConfigurationService has design problem. I'll update the answer with details.

Comment: Waiting for the configurationService correction. Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps. Notice that getToken should have .map().take(1) in order to efficiently converted to a promise. You need to return an observable, not a subscription.

Comment: in APP_INITIALIZER i have to load configService too. Other services dependent on configService are failing.  I have updated the code above on how configService is INITIALIZED. Why doesn't it initialize before routing?

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER is promise-based. If you expect it to not just instantiate the service but to wait for service intialization, It is `return () => config.configuration$.toPromise()`. I'd suggest to start adding strict types for functions, this can help to detect some errors (like the one with `.subscribe`).

Comment: On second thought, configurationPromise will do a better job here because it allows to avoid some caveats with observables. In this case it's just `return () => config.configurationPromise`.